# How do I use vim within a Unix pipe-line?

Tags: linux, ex-mode, unix

I can use vim / ex to grep a file using the following invocation:

`ex -c'g/foo/p' -cq -s afile.txt`

I'd really like to use a similar command to grep some text from stdin. I thought the following command should work, but it produces no output:

`cat afile.txt | ex -c'g/foo/p' -cq -s -`

The same thing happens if I use `vim -e` instead of `ex`:

`cat test.md | vim -e -c'g/foo/p' -cq -s -`

Is there any way that I can force ex to read its initial buffer from stdin and print output to stdout, so that it can be used within a Unix pipe-line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move the special filename `-` before `-e`:

```
cat test.md | vim -e -c'g/foo/p' -cq -s -
                                        ^
                                        ✘

cat test.md | vim - -e -c'g/foo/p' -cq -s
                  ^
                  ✔
```

Before `-e`, `-` is read as literal text.  After `-e`, `-` is read as an Ex command.

---

To suppress the `Vim: Reading from stdin...` warning, pass the `--not-a-term` argument to the `vim(1)` command:

```
cat test.md | vim - -e -c'g/foo/p' -cq -s --not-a-term
                                          ^----------^
```

---

To make Vim quit, execute `:qa!` instead of just `:q`:

```
cat test.md | vim - -e -c'g/foo/p' +'qa!' -s --not-a-term
                                     ^-^
```

---

You can join `-e` and `-s`, and you can replace `-c` with `+`:

```
cat test.md | vim - -es +'g/foo/p' +'qa!' --not-a-term
                      ^ ^
```

You should now be able to pass Vim's output to another shell utility; e.g. `wc(1)`:

```
cat test.md | vim - -es +'g/foo/p' +'qa!' --not-a-term | wc -l
                                                       ^-----^
```

---

See also:

- [vims](https://github.com/MilesCranmer/vim-stream)
- [Vim for pipeline filtering](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6262)
- [Vim's social life](https://vimways.org/2018/vims-social-life/)
- [my notes](https://github.com/lacygoill/wiki/blob/master/vim/ex.md)